# An example of a map that has no section but each of its fibers are not empty

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

"Conceptual mathematics" by Lawvere and Schanuel, 2nd ed. on page 82 says:

> ... If one fiber is empty, the map has no sections.  Furthermore, for
>   maps between finite sets the converse is also true: if no sort is
>   empty, then the map has a section.

Does it mean that there exist an *infinite* map whose fibers are all nonempty, but which does not have sections?  Can you give an example of such map?

I suspect the authors just mean that we need the axiom of choice to build such section, is it true?

Comment: Your suspicion is probably right -- but could you give some more context here? What kind of "map" is the quote about? Usually a section would be a section _of a fiber bundle_, not a section _of a map_, but that is clearly not the right context here.

Comment: These are the initial chapters of category theory and maps there are just plain set-theoretic maps. For $f: X \to B$ "we say that X is divided into B fibers".

Comment: Oh, now that you mention it, I have heard that terminology before. In that case the sentences you quote are clearly just taking care _not_ to assert the Axiom of Choice (one phrasing of which is "every map with no empty fiber has a section").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the axiom of choice is equivalent to every surjective function $f:A\to B$ (ie. map without empty fiber) admitting a right inverse: $h:B\to A\ $ (s.t. $f\circ h=id_B$).

For one part, if a family of nonempty sets $(A_b)_{b\in B}$ is given, let 
$$A:=\bigcup_{b\in B}\{b\}\times A_b \ \text{ and } \ f:=\langle b,a\rangle\mapsto b\ .$$
Then the right inverse of $f$ is nothing else but a choice function.